# sqlite adding a row based on existing rows

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having issues figuring out how to put the following together:

I have a sqlite table with a large number of columns.  Among these columns, one column is Name (the same name can show up multiple times) and another column is Year.  I need to go through Name and at each unique name check all the years that name has in all its rows looking for the years 2018, 2019, 2020, and 2021.  For each of these 4 years that isn't present for the current name, a new row needs added to the table with that Name, an assortment of other column values from the Names original row, and the missing year in Year.  Every other value needs to be left blank.

Edit:

Here's an example of a dataset

```
|  Name   |   Year   |  Favorite Color|
|  John   |   2018   |  Blue          |
|  John   |   2019   |  Blue          |
|  Jane   |   2020   |  Yellow        |
|  Jane   |   2021   |  Yellow        |
```

And here is the desired output:

```
|  Name   |   Year   |  Favorite Color|
|  John   |   2018   |  Blue          |
|  John   |   2019   |  Blue          |
|  John   |   2020   |  Blue          |
|  John   |   2021   |  Blue          |
|  Jane   |   2018   |  Yellow        |
|  Jane   |   2019   |  Yellow        |
|  Jane   |   2020   |  Yellow        |
|  Jane   |   2021   |  Yellow        |
```

But I end up with something more like this:

```
|  Name   |   Year   |  Color  |
|  John   |   2018   |  Blue   |
|  John   |   2019   |  Blue   |
|  John   |          |         |
|  John   |          |         |
|  Jane   |          |         |
|  Jane   |          |         |
|  Jane   |   2020   |  Yellow |
|  Jane   |   2021   |  Yellow |
```

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
            INSERT INTO final (
                
                Name,
                Year,
                Color
                               
            )
            WITH
                years (Year) AS (
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        Year
                FROM
                    final
                ),
                groupings (Name) AS (
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        Name
                    FROM
                        final
                ),
                backbone (Year, Name) AS (
                    SELECT
                        years.Year AS Year,
                        groupings.Name AS Name
                    FROM
                        years
                        CROSS JOIN groupings
                    )
                SELECT
        
                    backbone.Name AS Name,
                    backbone.Year,
                    final.Color
  
                    
                FROM
                    backbone
                    LEFT JOIN final USING (
                        Year, Name)

Any help is appreciated.
```

Comment: Write a subquery that returns the cross product between all the years and all the distinct names. Use `LEFT JOIN` to find all the missing ones. Use this query as the source data in `INSERT INTO table`

Comment: *...an assortment of other column values from the Names original row...* can you clarify this preferably with sample data and expected results?

Comment: Editted OP with my code, sample data set, and expected results

Comment: In the sample data you posted both rows for John and both rows for Jane have the same color. What if they have different colors?

Comment: The actual dataset will be going into a Tableau dashboard and certain columns (such as color) will be used as a filter, so I need certain column data to be held constant regardless of the year.  So, in the example, John's favorite color is always blue and I would be able to see that in Tableau when I filter.   Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

You can `CROSS` join all the years to the distinct name/color combinations and `LEFT` join to the table:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(name, year, favoritecolor)
SELECT n.name, y.year, n.favoritecolor
FROM (SELECT 2018 year UNION ALL SELECT 2019 UNION ALL SELECT 2020 UNION ALL SELECT 2021) y
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT name, favoritecolor  FROM tablename) n
LEFT JOIN tablename t ON (t.year, t.name) = (y.year, n.name)
WHERE t.name IS NULL
```

or with `CTE`s:

```
WITH 
  names(name, favoritecolor) AS (SELECT DISTINCT name, favoritecolor  FROM tablename),
  years(year) AS (VALUES (2018), (2019), (2020), (2021))
INSERT INTO tablename(name, year, favoritecolor)
SELECT n.name, y.year, n.favoritecolor
FROM years y CROSS JOIN names n
LEFT JOIN tablename t ON (t.year, t.name) = (y.year, n.name)
WHERE t.name IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=912fca4590e8265303f2b67df605a102).

If you want only the years currently stored in the table, then you can use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH 
  names(name, favoritecolor) AS (SELECT DISTINCT name, favoritecolor  FROM tablename),
  years(year) AS (
    SELECT MIN(year) FROM tablename
    UNION ALL
    SELECT year + 1 FROM years
    WHERE year < (SELECT MAX(year) FROM tablename)
  )
INSERT INTO tablename(name, year, favoritecolor)
SELECT n.name, y.year, n.favoritecolor
FROM years y CROSS JOIN names n
LEFT JOIN tablename t ON (t.year, t.name) = (y.year, n.name)
WHERE t.name IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=383a0ee78f3bf533d6acd8b697bcc223).

Results:

| name | year | favoritecolor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 2018 | Yellow |
| Jane | 2019 | Yellow |
| Jane | 2020 | Yellow |
| Jane | 2021 | Yellow |
| John | 2018 | Blue |
| John | 2019 | Blue |
| John | 2020 | Blue |
| John | 2021 | Blue |

Comment: Is it possible do this by selecting the years from the available years in that column (so, not hard coding in the years)?   This script needs to be able to be reused in later years  on datasets formatted similarly.

Comment: @HelpWithR see my edited answer with a 3d query.